# Docker VPN tunnel to remote database

Tags: php, docker, vpn, laradock

I am using Laradock to run a development version of a website.

It needs to access a database on Amazon through a VPN tunnel.

I have set up the VPN tunnel on my PC using Putty, so I have a local port 1234 forwarding to the remote DB port.

```
2021-07-05 07:33:12 Local port 1234 forwarding to mydb.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1234
```

How do I configure Laradock and/or Docker to use the tunnel on my local machine?

Alternatively how can I set up a tunnel that the Docker container can use?

**Edit:** Solved - see answer below

Comment: This seems to be a network problem? If you can access the remote database through the local port 1234, you only need to connect Laradock's network with the host computer and the local network, then Laradock can access the remote database through the host's ip and port

Comment: Yep it was a matter of working out how to do just that. Have solved it - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker containers use `host.docker.internal` as the hostname for your local system, so using it as the hostname for the database allows connection to the VPN tunnel.

Comment: Please be aware that `host.docker.internal` does not point to `127.0.0.1` (aka localhost) but to the IP of your network interface, e.g. `192.168.1.42` (see `hosts` file for the IP). The port forwarding must therefore bind to host `0.0.0.0` and not only localhost.

Comment: Seems to work with Putty which is all that matters as far as I'm concerned, but thanks